# How to refer to dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im creating dynamically a few of elements and i want to operate on them, so my code is somewhere about this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  $('#generateInput').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<div id="div' + (a) + '"><input name="Name' + (a) + '"></div>')
    $('#generateInput').hide()
  })

  $("#add").click(function addValue() {
    $('#inputValuesArea').append('<tr><td>' + '<input val="' + $('input[name="Name' + (a) + '"]').val() + '" readonly="readonly">' +
      '</td><td>' + '<button id="button' + (a) + '"type="button">Edit</button>' + '</td></tr>');
    $('#divArea').hide();
    $('#add').hide();
    $('#generateInput').show();
    a++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divArea">
</div><button id="generateInput">
    Generate
    </button>
<button id="add">
    Add
    </button>
<table id="inputValuesArea">
</table>
```

What im doing is: create input->hide it and append value to another input with button.
What i want is: If i create multiple inputs i want to `.show()` specific one to edit its value.
I dont know how to refer to this hidden input because i cant get his Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're appending multiple inputs and trying to allow editing of each when you click the edit button then you could identify the selected input based on its position using `eq` rather than it's `id` attribute.

The following allows adding multiple inputs and editing the `readonly` property to demonstrate but you can use the `currentInput` object to do whatever you need with it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  $('#generateInput').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<div id="div' + a + '"><input name="Name' + a + '"></div>')

    a++;
  });

  $("#add").click(function() {
    var nextInputVal = $('input[name="Name' + b + '"]').val();
    $('#inputValuesArea').append('<tr><td>' + '<input value="' + nextInputVal + '" readonly="readonly">' +
      '</td><td>' + '<button class="edit-button" id="button' + b + '"type="button">Edit</button>' + '</td></tr>');
    $('#divArea').hide();
    $('#generateInput').show();
    b++;
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.edit-button', function()
  {
    var pos = $('.edit-button').index($(this));
    var currentInput =  $('#inputValuesArea input').eq(pos);
    currentInput.removeAttr('readonly');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqcfsojv/2/

Answer (score 1):

In the following code:
- I keep the "Generate" button displayed for testing purposes,
- I created a function for you to console all the inputs newly created everytime you creates one,
- Note the new use and place of the variable 'a'
- Note that I am using the 'id' attribute to create a new input instead of using 'name' attribute, so that it becomes easier when trying to handle that new input
- Result, everytime you create new input it gets displayed in the console with all the previously created input, you can change that according to your needs

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="divArea">
  </div><button id="generateInput">
                Generate
                </button>
  <button id="add">
                Add
                </button>
  <table id="inputValuesArea">
  </table>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var a = 0;
      $('#generateInput').click(function() {
        a = a + 1;
        $('#divArea').append('<div id="div' + (a) + '"><input id="elementID' + (a) + '"></div>')
        //$('#generateInput').hide()   ;    
        consoleCreatedElements();
      })

      function consoleCreatedElements() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
          console.log($("#elementID" + i));
        }
      }

      $("#add").click(function addValue() {
        $('#inputValuesArea').append('<tr><td>' + '<input val="' + $('input[name="Name' + (a) + '"]').val() + '" readonly="readonly">' +
          '</td><td>' + '<button id="button' + (a) + '"type="button">Edit</button>' + '</td></tr>');
        $('#divArea').hide();
        $('#add').hide();
        $('#generateInput').show();
        a++;
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```